# Why pass the argument to vi as vi itself?

Tags: shell, process, vi, arguments, exec

Whats the reason behind passing the first argument to vi as vi itself like the following:

```
/bin/vi vi
```

Why not just write :

```
/bin/vi
```

The only difference that I have seen between the two commands is that executing `vi` without `vi` as the argument opens up `vim`, whereas if I supply `vi` as an argument it does not do so.

What's going on here?

Comment: I assume you're looking at some exec function calls (in e.g. strace)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Correct. Actually, I am looking at some tutorials for the `execl` function call, and this was the first example.

Comment: @ng.newbie, then [edit] your question to show the exact situation you mean. If you write `/bin/vi vi`, people will thinks it a command line, which would run `vi` on a file called `vi`.

Comment: @ilkkachu the vi binary seems to behave differently if it is invoked with an without vi as stated in the answer. That was my main question. I just happened to come across this via a `execl` call example.

Comment: @ilkkachu I was just agreeing with JeffSchaller that he was right his assumption. The question is about `vi` and not `execl`. Its something that I later ran on the command line and not via a `execl` call. I want people to think that it is about the command line, since that's what it's about.

Comment: Can you clarify in what context you'd be typing `/bin/vi vi` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick As I told you I got this example from a tutorial for the execl system call. I was confused by why vi needed vi in argv[0] and thats why I asked this question

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It mentioned a system call that is very similar to the call that you have mentioned. But again I repeat I wanted to know why `vi` would need the argument as `vi` in the function call. I did not know `/bin/vi vi` was different from the function call. In which the function call placed the argument in `argv[0]` while typing /bin/vi vi would place the argument in `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`execl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) takes the path of the command to run, followed by the arguments;

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.

which is why the first argument is `"vi"`.

You can think of this as specifying on the one hand the path of the command, and separately the `argv` array which the program receives (I’m simplifying a little here). It’s up to the caller to specify what the callee’s `argv[0]` will contain.

Programs can use `argv[0]` to adjust their behaviour; as you’ve seen, Vim behaves like Vi if it’s invoked as `vi`. Another example is `busybox` which implements a wide variety of commands in a single binary.

Comment: If you say vim behaves like vi, then this means the `vi` bin is actually pointing to a `vim` binary. Am I correct?

Comment: A follow-up question to your answer: When I execute `/bin/vi vi` the vi argument is going to argv[1] and not argv[0], so does vi adjust its behaviour based on argv[0] or argv[1] ?

Comment: So far nothing like this is present in the documentation something like this. Anywhere I can find this?

Comment: Yes, `vi` typically is the same binary as `vim`. If you execute `execl("/bin/vi", "vi")`, the `"vi"` argument ends up as `argv[0]` (which is what `vim` looks for); if you execute `/bin/vi vi` in your shell, `vi` ends up as `argv[1]` and `vi` tries to edit a file named `vi` in the current directory (you’ll likely see `"vi" [New File]` at the bottom of your screen). I provided a link to the documentation as the very first word of my answer.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the documentation of `vi` and not `execl` since this question was about the former.

Comment: Ah OK, I get it. Funnily enough I can’t find a reference to this behaviour, the documentation I checked (the manpage and the FAQ) mentions varying behaviour if Vim is started as `ex`, `view`, `gvim`, `evim`, or `rvim`, but not `vi`...

Comment: Actually there is a reference to it in the manpage, with the `-v` option: “Start  Vim in Vi mode, just like the executable was called "vi".”

Comment: Actually, a `/usr/bin/vi vi` opens up vim with a **new file** called `vi`.

Comment: @isaac right, hence the `[New File]` I mentioned in my comment (since the user is unlikely to have a file named `vi` in the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

If you write, on the command line of a standard, or standard-compatible shell, the command:

```
/bin/vi vi
```

then the shell will run `/bin/vi` with the argument `vi`. If you run

```
/bin/vi
```

instead, the shell will run just `/bin/vi`.

Actually, that's a simplification. On the system call level, the first will run `/bin/vi` with the arguments `/bin/vi` and `vi`, and the second just `/bin/vi`. Usually, we ignore the "zeroth" argument, it just contains the command name.

Now, I don't have `/bin/vi`, but `/usr/bin/vi` instead, and it's some version of VIM. Running

```
/usr/bin/vi vi
```

tells it it to open the file called `vi` in the current  directory. Running

```
/usr/bin/vi
```

just tells it to start, with no filename given, so it opens an unnamed buffer. In that case, at least this particular VIM also prints a greeting like the following:

```
~                               VIM - Vi IMproved
~
~                                 version 8.0.707
~                           by Bram Moolenaar et al.
~            Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
~                  Vim is open source and freely distributable
```

(it goes on with some useful commands like `:q` and `:help`.)

Some other versions of `vi` of course wouldn't print such a banner.